# HTML vertical Scroll (No CSS)

Tags: html, html-table, legacy, vertical-scroll

Is there any way to make content inside the table scrollable, just like `overflow:auto;` without using CSS's `overflow` property? I'm working of HTML 3.2 and IE 3.0 version so using CSS is not a good idea. The main point is, lots of CSS property is not supported so I need to make it using only Table.

Comment: I'm also curious, why does it need to support HTML 3.2?

Comment: Are you developing for Flinstones?

Comment: He comes from the past ! Doc Emmett Brown has troubles coding in 1985 ?

Comment: I think you can use CSS 1.0 at least. Have you tried `style="overflow:scroll;"` ? I can't find out if overflow is a CSS 1.0 property

Comment: @Apolo MDN says "overflow" starts with ie4: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Browser_Kompatibilit.C3.A4t

Comment: good to know :) seems like Jegannath has the answer

Comment: Thank you all for your kind replies. Actually, I'm working with an abc company and it have several hundreds of Kiosk machine installed different parts of the country which have ie3 browser installed. I tried using CSS overflow but due to limited support of CSS properties in HTML 3.2, I couldn't use this as well. I hope this helps to reply some of you and expecting new answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword **scrolling=yes/no/auto**. This is widely used in HTML3.2 and HTML3.0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, time traveler. and have your first upvote.